# Is there a fast way to modify consistent components of a nested list in R?

Tags: r, nested-lists

I have a vector of values that I wish to use to modify a consistent component of a nested list. Currently I'm using a for loop to do this which is proving quite slow and I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do it.

By way of reproducible example:

```
#Create Data and List
set.seed(100)
Students <- c("Amy", "Ben", "Caz")
Subject <- c("Maths", "English", "Science")

ExamResults <- lapply(Students, function (r) {
  Scores <- lapply(Subject, function(x) round(runif(4, 0, 100)))
  names(Scores) <- Subject
  Scores
})
names(ExamResults) <- Students
```

Which creates a list that looks like this:

```
$Amy
$Amy$Maths
[1] 31 26 55  6

$Amy$English
[1] 47 48 81 37

$Amy$Science
[1] 55 17 62 88

$Ben
$Ben$Maths
[1] 28 40 76 67

$Ben$English
[1] 20 36 36 69

$Ben$Science
[1] 54 71 54 75

$Caz
$Caz$Maths
[1] 42 17 77 88

$Caz$English
[1] 55 28 49 93

$Caz$Science
[1] 35 95 70 89
```

Now let's say the second maths paper for all students is remarked:

```
#New Data
MathsRemark <- c(24, 50, 45) #assume in correct (alphabetical) order
```

And we wish to modify their existing second maths score for these new values. My current solution for doing this is:

```
#Current Slow Solution
for (i in 1:length(Students)) {
  ExamResults[[i]][["Maths"]][[2]] <- MathsRemark[i]
}
```

On larger datasets this is proving very slow. Is anyone aware of a faster way to do this? 
I've been taught to avoid using for loops where vectorising is possible but I can't figure out how to vectorise this problem. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question can be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950336/use-to-modify-a-nested-list-within-a-functional

Answer (score 6):

One option is `Map()`.

```
Map(function(x, y) { x$Maths[2] <- y; x }, ExamResults, MathsRemark)
```

A second option is to unlist, replace, and relist.

```
u <- unlist(ExamResults)
relist(replace(u, endsWith(names(u), "Maths2"), MathsRemark), ExamResults)
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, unfortunately neither seem to be faster. The `Map()` solution only seems to be quicker with small lists.

Answer (score 2):

I want to point out that the next release of `purrr` is going to have [`assign_in`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/modify_in.html), which will allow to very elegantly express your solution as:

```
library( purrr )
map2( ExamResults, MathsRemark, assign_in, where=list("Maths",2) )
```

However, it's not nearly as fast as @Rich Scriven's solution:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    f0 = for (i in 1:length(Students))
         {ExamResults[[i]][["Maths"]][[2]] <- MathsRemark[i]},
    f1 = map2( ExamResults, MathsRemark, assign_in, where=list("Maths",2) ),
    f2 = Map(function(x, y) { x$Maths[2] <- y; x }, ExamResults, MathsRemark)
)
# Unit: microseconds
# expr      min        lq       mean    median       uq      max neval
#   f0 2148.158 2258.7700 2580.87901 2333.9455 2741.233 4550.022   100
#   f1  180.081  206.7990  247.42790  235.8160  254.058 1310.912   100
#   f2    9.410   14.7515   33.05673   18.8505   19.943 1558.125   100
```

Comment: Thanks for this Artem, any idea when the next release of `purrr` will be available? Unfortunately the `Map()` function seems to perform significantly slower on larger lists. As an example I get: 
   `f0  293.370  330.5755 2225.629  567.9235 3819.797  10960.75   100`
   `f2 3511.032 3709.6050 6312.285 3860.7090 4333.693 130174.74   100`

Comment: Hi @WillT-E. I'm not sure what the timeline is for the release appearing on CRAN, but you can install it right now directly from GitHub: https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off turning your original list into a dataframe and then modifying. `map` from the purrr package could help with this.

```
library(tidyverse)

extract_subject_df<- function(specific_subject){
# Outputs a dataframe for a specific subject
    ExamResults %>% 
        map(specific_subject) %>%
        data.frame() %>%
        mutate(specific_subject=specific_subject)
}

new_df <- map_df(Subject, extract_subject_df)

new_df[new_df$specific_subject == "Maths"][2, 1:3] <- c(24, 50, 45)
```